# Wrapping a namespace with a self-executing function

Tags: javascript

I'm building a game and was trying to figure out the workings of the `melonJS` game engine I am using. I'm at a point where I need to create my own version of their CanvasRender object, so was trying to understand what they've done.

Why wrap the canvas renderer in an anonymous, self-invoking function? Can't I just create the function as such?

```
    me.CanvasRenderer = me.CanvasRenderer || {};

    me.CanvasRenderer = {
        init: function() {
        //...
```

Or even within a namespace:

```
  var CanvasStuff = {
       CanvasRenderer : function() {

       }
  };
  CanvasStuff.CanvasRenderer();
```

I don't understand how they've laid out this code and the purpose. How and when is `(function () {` invoked?

Here's a snippet of their code: ([link to full code](https://github.com/melonjs/melonJS/blob/1.1.x/src/video/canvas_renderer.js))

```
(function () {

    // The canvas renderer object
    me.CanvasRenderer = (function () {
          var api = {},
          var canvas = null, 
          //...
          api.init = function () {
             //...
          };
          return api;
          //...
   })();
})();
```

Comment: read up on [singleton pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern)

Comment: I think the OP knows what the singleton pattern is... There really is no reason for the additional wrapping. Perhaps they anticipated including some variables within the first self invoking function. Thus defining a SEF would help so you wouldnt bleed any variables out. Its possible other objects use this same pattern and the designer didnt want to break the pattern

Comment: @cgatian well that's a singleton pattern and OP is asking why they would do that, so I tend to disagree with your assumption of OP's knowledge!

Comment: He asks why do you wrap it. He obviously knows the singleton pattern by using the object || {}

Comment: I could be wrong though as your pointing out, since he doesn't know when the anonymous function is invoked. I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The self-invoking function is executed immediately, so it is similar to the alternatives you posted.

However, the advantage of the self-invoking function is that you can declare variables within that scope that are not accessible outside the closure. For example, in the code snippet you posted there is a `var canvas` that is accessible within any of the api functions, but not accessible to any outside code. In the first alternative you suggested, there is no way to declare `canvas` without it being accessible to any clients/callers of the api. Your second alternative (the namespace) isn't filled out enough to see how it would be used, so you might be able to wrap private vars into that closure as well.